# Sending information to a specific column in a database C#

Tags: c#, database

I Have a table with 3 columns, when an alarm goes off, I want the time of that alarm to be stored in the 2nd column of the table(AlarmActivated). Then if that alarm is turned off, it stores that time in the same row of the table but in column 3. This is my code:

```
String ConStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PatientHealthMonitor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
String Query = " INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES" + (DateTime.Now.ToString());
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);
Con.Open();
Command.ExecuteReader();
Con.Close();
```

This is executed when a value goes to 0.

Comment: do you have a specific problem you are having trouble with?

Comment: You cannot do insert on a same row many times. You try inserting first and then with its uniqueID update the other 2 columns. You need to describe the table clearly so that we can have a good picture of what you want

Comment: @MohanPrasath you one can clearly see that the problem is not with describing the table but that building his query string he's missing the closing `")"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteReader` returns some data. Since you wanna insert, you need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead.

And do **not** store your `DateTime` values as a `string`. Change your column type to `datetime2` and pass your `DateTime.Now` value directly to your [parameterized query](http://ttp://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Please read [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Also using `DateTime.Now` *can* be ambigious. Read Matt's article [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Since you insert only one column, other two columns will be `null` or their default value.

```
string ConStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PatientHealthMonitor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

using(var Con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
using(var Command = Con.CreateCommand())
{
   Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES (@alarm)";
   Command.Parameters.Add("@alarm", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
   Con.Open();
   Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I didn't develop the database, however I have changed it to datetime2, thank you!

Comment: Since this answer touches on bad habit correction... to go along with what Soner mentioned regarding your datetime column, you seem to be passing DateTime.Now directly. If this is a field that the user will not be manipulating before saving, I would suggest not even passing a value from the UI. Use the built in date/time functions of your DBMS to generate a value to store: `INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: @gmiley This can be another option as well but AFAIK, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is vulnerable by time zone _weirdness_ as `DateTime.Now` since it derives the computer where this sql instance is running and it can have different _meaning_ in different places. Using `UTC` time and storing them is a better approach or course.

Comment: @SonerGönül - No, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` uses the users session information to return the proper local time of the connected user, `SYSTIMESTAMP` is the local time of the server. I should add also that in most cases, for enterprise level applications, the date/time localization should be handled on the client side to avoid timezone confusion. If you database servers have regional failovers, then that would be a case where you really should be storing in UTC.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
String Query = " INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES" + (DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

It has to be

```
String Query = " INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES (" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

wrong function is used, use this function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 1):

First, your string for your insert is badly formed.  You need to put the parentheses inside quotes:

```
String Query = " INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +"')";
```

Secondly, you need to use *parameterized* queries instead, because building your SQL like this is a bad habit to get into and can lead to SQL  injection breaches:

```
String ConStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PatientHealthMonitor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
String Query = " INSERT INTO AlarmResponse (AlarmActivated) VALUES (@alarmTime)";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);

Con.Open();
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alarmTime", DateTime.Now);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Con.Close();
```

Finally, only the column AlarmActivated will be set with a value.  The other two columns will be populated by their default value.  If you want the other two columns to have a value other than their default, you need to specify them and provide a value.

Comment: Tells me there is an invalid column name, yet when looking at my table AlarmActivated is the name of the column. EDIT: My Database guy named it with two e's -_-

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 stored procedures in SQL, one will insert row and return @@SCOPE_IDENTITY (you can store it in list<>), which you will use as a param for updating procedure.

Try to avoid using SQL statemensts in code, to prevent code injection.